# Three time same class instance but slightly different instance values

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a class with a bunch of instance variables. Now I want to create three instances of this class, where most of the values are same, but only a few of them have different values. Are there some possibilities or concepts to do this without (deep) cloning one instance? Are subclasses for these instances the best way?

I have thought about cloning one instance, but my classes are deep nested and also this seems to be inefficient.

This is the class I have. In my case, most of the variables stay the same but shortDescription has different values among those three instances.

```js
export default class Event extends Base {
  public id!: number;
  public afterbuyId!: number;
  public shopId!: number;

  public name!: string;
  public sellingPrice!: number;
  public taxRate!: number;
  public level!: number;
  public shortDescription!: string;
  public startDate!: Date;
  public startTime!: Date;
  public endDate!: Date;
  public endTime!: Date;
  public quantityCheckProduct!: boolean;
  public active!: boolean;

  public venues: Venue[] = [];
  public bundles: Bundle[] = [];
  public paymentMethods: PaymentMethod[] = [];
  public deliveryMethods: DeliveryMethod[] = [];
  public categories: Category[] = [];
}
```

Ignore the fact, that the variables are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already found a solution. I'll return an array of objects consisting of the needed variables and their values:

```js
public generateRequestObject(): any {
    return [
      {
        "name": this.name,
        "sellingPrice": this.sellingPrice
      },
      {
        "name": `MP ${this.name}`,
        "sellingPrice": this.sellingPrice
      }
    ];
  }
```

Comment: You have now lost type-safety by constructing object literals of type `any`. If that is not a problem for you, then yes this is one solution, but I hope that you understand that you now need to validate all the other member variables. I am not one for waving design patterns at every problem, but based on your question phrasing, the Builder pattern is exactly what you need.

Comment: Or you can define a type for `RequestObject`, so the function will become: `public generateRequestObject(): RequestObect { ... }`